# Why OutOfMemoryError does not generated?

Tags: java, linux, shell, out-of-memory

I have my java-written application being "killed" after some time of work.

Java application is started from SH script under Linux, which is running for some time. After then the PID displayed and "killed" word said.

Like this:

```
runMyServer.sh: line 3: 3593 Killed         java -Xmx2024m -cp ...
```

There is information about out of memory event in the system log. So it looks like out of memory error.

My question is: when OutOfMemroyError exception can be not generating?

Comment: What does the entry in the system log look like?  can you paste it here?

Comment: try running the application without the .sh script. I think it IS generated, just nou displayed.

Comment: @11684 how can I reproduce the situation, when application is said "killed"?

Comment: @Amir will post after administrator give it to me :)

Comment: Note that you only get OutOfMemoryError if the Java heap has grown to its max allowed size and you're still demanding space for new objects.  If, instead, your application runs out of the memory space allotted by the operating system, the OS will kill the app without signalling a Java exception.

Comment: @Hot are you sure? This means that I can't control out of memory errors actually!

Comment: I hate to break it to you, but you'll find that there are lots of things you can't control.

Comment: @Dims Probably you have a `java etc...` call in your .sh script that starts the app that is getting killed. Could you try to o that `java` command exactly as it's in there? Then we will see what's happening.

Comment: or could you post the .sh script?

Comment: @Hot, this is not about philosophy. It was strange discovery for me that Java creators made `OutOfMemoryError` exception not for out of memory condition, but for heap quota condition (actually).

Comment: You're obviously new to programming.  (And, technically, effectively handling an out of memory error is ***very*** difficult.  Consider that, if you're out of memory, you can't create any objects.)

Comment: @Hot I feel new to programming each God's day :)

Comment: @Dims: Java out of memory aren't triggered by heap quota conditions but, amongst other possible reasons, by a real JVM out of memory situation. In any case, your JVM doesn't reach this OOM state, the linux kernel is just killing it because it lied to the JVM and was later busted by this lie. Linux has been designed and is configured by default to behave that way. To avoid that unpleasant situation, you might consider the suggestion I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have too little memory on your system or run processes that eat up all ram and swap. When GNU/Linux runs out of memory it will kill processes using much memory. This is basically just kill on the process, so it is not you Java process running out of memory, but rather the OS.

Comment: How to prevent the system to kill my program? Why doesn't it kill something else? I have 6G and my java heap is limited to 2G.

Comment: @Dims How much free memory do you have? Are there other processes using the same amount or more ram? Basically the process with biggest ram/cpu time is killed, so the more ram and and less cpu the higher likelihood of being killed. How much ram does your java prices use, it will use more than the heap. Here is more information http://lwn.net/Articles/317814/

Comment: Sure I have another processes and one of them is mine and wants 3G. I understand that I can have insufficient memory, but I want to control the situation...

Answer (score 0):

To avoid your java application to be killed by the OOM killer just add enough swap to your system and disable memory overcomitting.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=2048
chmod 600 /swapfile
mkswap /swapfile
swapon /swapfile
echo "/swapfile               swap                    swap    defaults        0 0" >> /etc/fstab
echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
```